# Unfinished Block Diagram

Tags: diagrams

I am trying to replicate this block diagram.

[image]

This is the best I can do for now.

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{schemabloc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \sbStyleBloc{thick}
    \sbEntree{E}
    \sbComp{comp}{E}
    \sbRelier{E}{comp}
    \sbNomLien[0.8]{E}{$R(s)$}
    \sbBloc[2]{reg}{$G_1(s)$}{comp}
    \sbRelier{comp}{reg}
    \sbCompSum[5]{comp2}{reg}{+}{}{+}{}
    \sbRelier{reg}{comp2}
    \sbBloc[2]{reg2}{$G_2(s)$}{comp2}
    \sbRelier{comp2}{reg2}
    \sbSortie[4]{S}{reg2}
    \sbRelier{reg2}{S}
    \sbNomLien[0.8]{S}{$C(s)$}
    \sbDecaleNoeudy[4]{S}{U}
    \sbBlocr[8.7]{cap}{$H(s)$}{U}
    \sbRelieryx{reg2-S}{cap}
    \sbRelierxy{cap}{comp}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Can anyone help me add the D(s) input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to produce the correct diagram.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{schemabloc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \sbStyleBloc{thick}
    \sbEntree{E}
    \sbComp{comp}{E}
    \sbRelier{E}{comp}
    \sbNomLien[0.8]{E}{$R(s)$}
    \sbBloc[2]{reg}{$G_1(s)$}{comp}
    \sbRelier{comp}{reg}
    \sbCompSum[5]{comp2}{reg}{+}{}{+}{}
    \sbRelier{reg}{comp2}
    \sbBloc[2]{reg2}{$G_2(s)$}{comp2}
    \sbRelier{comp2}{reg2}
    \sbSortie[4]{S}{reg2}
    \sbRelier{reg2}{S}
    \sbNomLien[0.8]{S}{$C(s)$}
    \sbDecaleNoeudy[4]{S}{U}
    \sbBlocr[8.7]{cap}{$H(s)$}{U}
    \sbRelieryx{reg2-S}{cap}
    \sbRelierxy{cap}{comp}
    %
    \sbDecaleNoeudy[-3]{comp2}{D}
    \sbRelier{D}{comp2}
    \sbNomLien{D}{$D(s)$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The vertical position of the "D(s)" can be adjusted with the optional argument in the line

```
\sbDecaleNoeudy[-3]{comp2}{D}
```